# SSH Google Authenticator Ignore/Whitelist ips

Tags: google-authenticator

I installed google authenticator (two step verification), "libpam-google-authenticator" package, although it asks for a code for every single connection to SSH. I want to put localhost and my own ip whitelisted from google authenticator so I and localhost skip two step verification

Or is there a way to skip SSH challenge for certain ips?

Comment: Are you using public key or password for authentication?

Comment: Using password authentication plus two step verification, but I figured it out now

Comment: Public key authentication has some security advantages which I don't think it is possible to achieve through the PAM interface. For that reason I suspect public key authentication is more secure than what you are doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Factor SSH Authentication on external address only](http://serverfault.com/questions/518802/two-factor-ssh-authentication-on-external-address-only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In "/etc/pam.d/sshd"

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Then on "/etc/security/access-local.conf"

```
#localhost doesn't need two step verification
+ : ALL : 192.168.1.0/24
+ : ALL : LOCAL
+ : ALL : YOURIPHERE
#All other hosts need two step verification
- : ALL : ALL
```

Don't forget to restart ssh