# SSH disabling google-authenticator from specific IP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam, ubuntu-18.04, google-authenticator

I have setup google-authenticator as 2FA together with publickey authentication. What I need is to skip the 2FA when connecting by SSH from specific IP.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Relevant snippet from of /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service
# Standard Un*x authentication.
#@include common-auth
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
auth    required    pam_google_authenticator.so
# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account
```

/etc/security/access-local.conf

```
#localhost doesn't need two step verification
+ : ALL : 192.168.1.20
#All other hosts need two step verification
- : ALL : ALL
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin no 

PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam

/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

The result

```
Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).
```

I have restarted sshd after every change, even tried to reboot the machine.

Before marking this as a duplicate I have tried all these answers, none of them seems to work, also several other resources on the Internet:

[SSH Google Authenticator Ignore/Whitelist ips](https://serverfault.com/questions/799657/ssh-google-authenticator-ignore-whitelist-ips)

[Two Factor SSH Authentication on external address only](https://serverfault.com/questions/518802/two-factor-ssh-authentication-on-external-address-only)

At this point I'm not sure what am I missing.

Edit: I changed the question, the original was about connecting from localhost which as was pointed out by michael-hampton in the comments was useless. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you having ansible ssh to the local host?

Comment: I didn't read the documentation and automatically assumed it needed SSH access without actually checking. Well that was a waste of time. I'll edit the question, because it still has problems when using remote IP.

Comment: Is the answer to the present question provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388384/ssh-only-require-google-authenticator-from-outside-local-network)?